# Using a Zend_Db_Expr

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

I have the following query:

```
$select = $this->getDao()->select()
                         ->from(
                           array(new Zend_Db_Expr('FROM_UNIXTIME(expiration)'))
                           );
```

The getDao function is a reference to my Data Access object class which looks like this:

```
class Model_Db_AccountresetDao extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'accountreset';
    protected $_primary = 'reset_id';
}
```

Now i get this following error:

> "Select query cannot join with another
>   table"

This while i don't want to do a join. I just want to select that field as a unixTimestamp

How can I solve this problem?

All help is appreciated.

Tnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are gettin select object from Zend_Db_Table_Abstract you can't pass him a `->from()`. I think you should do like this

```
$select = $this->getDao()->select()  
                         ->from(this->getDao(),
                           array('_date or some field='.new Zend_Db_Expr('FROM_UNIXTIME(expiration)'))
                           );
```

or something like this.

Comment: But then it become a condition and i don't want it to be a condition. I just want to select that field in a different format.

Comment: ->from give's the select object table name to select from, you should you ->select(array('date'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('FROM_UNIXTIME(expiration)') to pass fields you wanna select